# How to provide activity or application context in Hilt to ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context, dagger-hilt

Hello I have a button in `recyclerview`, I would like to show dialog when in one element of recyclerview the button is clicked.

I have done:

in Adapter:

```
class SetGoalsAdapter(
    private val onItemDeleteClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val onItemRootClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val onButtonClickedListener: (Int) -> Unit)
[...more code...]

                btnQuestion.setOnClickListener() {
                    onButtonClickedListener(item.id)
                }
```

in VM:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SetGoalsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
)

[...more code]

    fun onItemButtonQuestionClicked(id: Int) {
        CustomSetGoalsDialog(context, id).show("TESTTITLE",
            "ARE YOU SURE ABOUT IT?") {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                it.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

CustomSetDialog

```
class CustomSetGoalsDialog (context: Context, id: Int) : AlertDialog.Builder(context) {

    lateinit var onResponse: (r : ResponseType) -> Unit

    enum class ResponseType {
        YES, NO, CANCEL
    }

    fun show(title: String, message: String, listener: (r : ResponseType) -> Unit) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setTitle(title)
        builder.setMessage(message)
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        onResponse = listener

        // performing positive action
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
            onResponse(ResponseType.YES)
        }

        // performing negative action
        builder.setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ ->
            onResponse(ResponseType.NO)
        }

        // performing cancel action
        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
            onResponse(ResponseType.CANCEL)
        }

        // Create the AlertDialog
        val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

        // Set other dialog properties
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
        alertDialog.show()
    }
}
```

From my understanding if button is clicked method from VM is triggered and it happens, but with error and as I consider this is the context problem. How to solve it?

Error:

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Comment: Did you try changing the @ApplicationContext context annotation in SetGoalsViewModel to @ActivityContext?

Comment: Yes and I cant provide it well I think it isn't by default.

Comment: try to cast context as activity (eg context as MainActivity) when creating dialog where MainActivity is the activity in which button is clicked

Comment: Tried many things and it didn't work. I made flow to trigger button and make function vm.triggerAcceptDeclineButton.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner) { HERE OPEN DIALOG with CONTEXT FROM FRAGMENT} and it is much efficient, better solution and context is not attached to Vm. Thanks! :)